# Конвертация координат latitude & longitute в UTM

Tags: c++, qt

Пытаюсь понять, как работает конвертация координаторов из `latitute` и `longitute` в `UTM`. Нашел также на сайте `GeographicLib` пример

```
// Example of using the GeographicLib::UTMUPS class
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <exception>
#include <string>
#include <GeographicLib/UTMUPS.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace GeographicLib;
int main() {
  try {
    // See also example-GeoCoords.cpp
    {
      // Sample forward calculation
      double lat = 33.3, lon = 44.4; // Baghdad
      int zone;
      bool northp;
      double x, y;
      UTMUPS::Forward(lat, lon, zone, northp, x, y);
      string zonestr = UTMUPS::EncodeZone(zone, northp);
      cout << fixed << setprecision(2)
           << zonestr << " " << x << " " << y << "\n";
    }
    {
      // Sample reverse calculation
      string zonestr = "38n";
      int zone;
      bool northp;
      UTMUPS::DecodeZone(zonestr, zone, northp);
      double x = 444e3, y = 3688e3;
      double lat, lon;
      UTMUPS::Reverse(zone, northp, x, y, lat, lon);
      cout << lat << " " << lon << "\n";
    }
  }
  catch (const exception& e) {
    cerr << "Caught exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Но он не работает. Помоги пожалуйста написать простой код, конвертации.

Ошибки которые выскакивают при компиляции данного кода. Какие параметры и для чего они ему нужны, я не понял.

```
undefined reference to `GeographicLib::UTMUPS::EncodeZone(int, bool, bool)'
undefined reference to `GeographicLib::UTMUPS::Forward(double, double, int&, bool&, double&, double&, double&, double&, int, bool)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Что конкретно не работает?

Comment: @zed ошибка выскакивает тут `UTMUPS::Forward(lat, lon, zone, northp, x, y);` весь код скопирован с сайта.

Comment: Какая ошибка? Почему вас за язык надо тянуть? Давайте максимальную информацию о проблеме, если хотите получить помощь.

Comment: @zed я не могу в данный момент ее написать, так как я не нахожусь рядом с пк.

Comment: @zed добавил недостающюю информацию

Comment: Линковщик не может найти указанные функции. Вы ему в параметрах указали, что нужно линковаться с `GeographicLib`? Или вы просто подключили заголовочник, а про бинарник с реализацией забыли?

Comment: @zed немного не понял про какой бинарник вы говорите

Comment: Тот, который с расширением `.lib` или `.a`. Вы, наверное, просто не умеете подключать сторонние библиотеки. См. справку: http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake-libraries.html Возможно, вам придётся пересобрать своим компилятором эту либу из сорцов самому, а потом уже подключать.

Comment: @zed тогда почему в документации написано `In order to use GeographicLib from C++ code, you will need to

Include the header files for the GeographicLib classes in your code. E.g.,
#include <GeographicLib/LambertConformalConic.hpp> 
Include the GeographicLib:: namespace prefix to the GeographicLib classes, or include
using namespace GeographicLib; 
in your code.`

Comment: Всё правильно написано, это надо делать. Но там ещё не написано, что для успешной компиляции, линковщику нужно указывать где находится реализация тех функций, что описаны в `hpp` файлах. А вы думали всё так просто?

Comment: @zed собрал и вставил `.pro LIBS += -lGeographic`
. `Выдает ошибку error while loading shared libraries: libGeographic.so.17: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68703/discussion-between-insider-and-zed).